# Crystal Report: Display Image from Database Failing

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have been trying to show an image in my crystal report. I am able to get the path from database. i placed the path in my crystal report. instead of showing the image , it shows the path.

```
for (int rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < dataTable.Rows.Count; rowNumber++)
{
    string imgName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(dataTable.Rows[rowNumber]["logopath"].ToString());
    DisplayImages(dataTable.Rows[rowNumber], "logopath", imgName);
}


private void DisplayImages(DataRow row, string img, string ImagePath)
{
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(ImagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    byte[] ImgData = new byte[stream.Length];

    stream.Read(ImgData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length));
    stream.Close();

    row[img] = ImgData;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNJP7.jpg)

can you suggest me what i am missing.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating a PictureObject, put the picture on it and then add it to the report, take a look at the following code:

```
    private void PictureData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.PictureObject boPictureObject;
        CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.Section boSection;

        rpt.Load("D:\\CPP Net\\RASXIR2Printer\\oleobject.rpt");
        rptClientDoc = rpt.ReportClientDocument;

        String MyfilePath = "C:\\temp\\sample1.jpg";

        //Determine which section to add the picture field to - in this case the report header section
        boSection = rptClientDoc.ReportDefController.ReportDefinition.ReportHeaderArea.Sections[0];

        //Add it to the report
        boPictureObject = rptClientDoc.ReportDefController.ReportObjectController.ImportPicture(MyfilePath, boSection, 1, 1);

    }
```

http://scn.sap.com/thread/2051483

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But i am afraid it does not work in CR 13.

Comment: You may need to add a reference to `ReportDefModel`, `ClientDoc` and `Controllers` since I'm working right now with this piece of code and it does work

Comment: Thank You .. I will have a go at it.